# Imagen carga desajustada swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hola en mi proyecto de xcode con swift agregue una galeria de imagenes estilo carrusel lo que ocurre en este caso es que siempre que cargó la imagen la primera vez sale corrida hacia abajo y con un espacio blanco arriba solo ocurre en la primera imagen y cuando la presiona se soluciona lo cual no es la idea y debería cargar ok desde un inicio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Necesitamos más detalles para ayudarte. ¿Utilizas un `UIScrollView`? ¿una librería de terceros? O si es posible, sube el proyecto a Dropbox o similar para echarle un vistazo, ya que con tan pocos datos es imposible saber qué pasa...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bic8a91wqr9a7h/Patagonia%20Viva.zip?dl=0 ahi esta gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade la siguiente línea de código en el `viewDidLoad` del `UIPageViewController`

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciona perfecto. me gustaría hacerte una pregunta ya que viste el proyecto, si te fijaste cada una de esas páginas corresponde a un lugar los cuales deberían tener su propia galería de imagen como podria hacer para enviarle a la galería el arreglo de fotos correspondiente a cada lugar? es un problema grande que tengo y lo último que me falta se agradeceria mucho tu ayuda en esto.

Comment: Eso lo tendrás que hacer por código. Al pulsar sobre el icono de la cámara es el lugar donde pasarle el `Array` de imágenes.

Comment: eso tenía en mente. con el sistema override func prepareForSegue pero funcionaria así?

Comment: Bueno, básicamente sería lo mismo que cuando instancias el `UIPageViewController` que le pasas un par de parámetros.